# Resize element in grid container in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, grid

I have grid container with cells and one draggable item in Vue. I need to resize box inside grid component(look images).

[image]

This is my grid, and I want that this box resize by cells in grid. Something like

[image]

I need draggable border resize.

This is my template for this component in Vue.

```
<template>
  <div v-bind:class="containerClass">
    <div v-bind:class="addNewItemContainerClass">
      <button>Add new box</button>
    </div>
    <div v-bind:class="drugAndDropContainerClass">
      <div v-bind:class="drugAndDropClass">
        <div
          v-bind:class="dragAndDropItemClass"
          v-for="n in 256"
          :key="n"
          @drop="drop"
          @dragover="allowDrop"
        >
          <div
            v-if="n === 1"
            v-bind:class="boxClass"
            v-bind:id="n"
            draggable="true"
            @dragstart="drag"
          ></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is my css style

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: fit-content;
}

.addNewItemContainer {
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-bottom: black 1px solid;
}

.drugAndDropContainer {
  background-color: #DAF0F7;
  padding: 10px;

  height: 100%;
}

.drugAndDrop {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(16, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
}

.dragAndDropItem {
  content: "";
  background-color: #C8D9F0;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.box {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  width: 99px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS Grid has some additional properties for this case i.e.

```
.item {
  grid-column-start: <number> | <name> | span <number> | span <name> | auto;
  grid-column-end: <number> | <name> | span <number> | span <name> | auto;
  grid-row-start: <number> | <name> | span <number> | span <name> | auto;
  grid-row-end: <number> | <name> | span <number> | span <name> | auto;
}
```

Example

```
.item-a {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: five;
  grid-row-start: row1-start;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}
```

[image]

If no grid-column-end/grid-row-end is declared, the item will span 1 track by default.

You can also use grid-template-areas:

```
.item-a {
  grid-area: header;
}
.item-b {
  grid-area: main;
}
.item-c {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}
.item-d {
  grid-area: footer;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header header"
    "main main . sidebar"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but my box is inside grid cel, and when I add `grid-column-start: 2`, there is no effect. I need box inside div, and this box must be movable and resizable inside the grid.

Comment: You can use the second option to name the div and according to the drag and drop area you can update the grid cell. For that, there are many ways to achieve.
One way you can try like this https://codesandbox.io/s/j4vn761455?file=/src/App.vue